# Javascript each loop through sliders settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm trying to do an each loop for the settings of my slick sliders.

The content in settings is as following:

```
$('.slider1').slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  swipe: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  prevArrow: ".pp1",
  nextArrow: ".nn1",
});

$('.slider2').slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  swipe: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  prevArrow: ".pp2",
  nextArrow: ".nn2",
});
```

So each slider needs basically the same settings, But with the selector and the class in `prevArrow` and `nextArrow` upping one for each. They all have a common parent wrapper called `.slider-wrapper`.

I guess I have to do a each loop of the parent, get child element.

slider `+=1` and use `+=1` at the `prev/next` settings as well.

```
var prev = '.pp';
var next = '.nn';
var sliders = '.slider';
function prevAdd() {
    return prev += 1;
};

function nextAdd() {
    return next += 1;
};

function slidersAdd() {
    return sliders += 1;
};

$.each('.slider-wrapper').child(slidersAdd()).slick({
    prevArrow: prevAdd(),
    // various settings
});
```

This is probably full of errors, But it's pretty much the best I could work out on my own.

EDIT: Html markup

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="slider-nav>
         <button class="pp1">prev</button>
         <button class="nn1">next</button>
    </div>
    <div class="slider1">
        <!-- list of divs for slider elements. Irrelevant for problem -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="slider-nav>
         <button class="pp2">prev</button>
         <button class="nn2">next</button>
    </div>
    <div class="slider2">
        <!-- list of divs for slider elements. Irrelevant for problem -->
    </div>
</div>
```

and so on with multiple sliders.

Comment: Please can you show the relevant ("*[mcve]*") HTML this is working with?

Comment: Why do you have different class for each prev button? Do they all have a different style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sliders all have the class `slider`, then you could do this, applying the `each` method on the selected element collection:

```
$('.slider-wrapper .slider').each(function (index, slider) {
    var id = index + 1; 
    $(slider).slick({
        prevArrow: ".pp" + id,
        nextArrow: ".nn" + id,
        // various settings
    });
});
```

If you don't have the `slider` class on every slider element, but a class with a unique number suffixed to it, then use this selector:

```
$('.slider-wrapper [class^=slider]').each( // ...etc
```

But really, you should not assign different classes to each slider. A class name is not a unique identifier. You can reuse it for similar elements.

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Thanks for the quick reply, saved me from a lot of fumbling around :)

Comment: Emphasis added to **you should not assign different classes to [the navigation elements of] each slider.**

Comment: You're welcome. Consider the comments on class names: try to use the same classes where this is logical: one for all your sliders, one for all your prev buttons, and a third one for all your next buttons.

Comment: I'm using slick.js, which need to have different container and prev/next button selectors. I suppose i could have given them the same selector and added extra classes for seperation through javascript.